# How to iterate over the rows in one dataframe and append them to another if a condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe called `df_a` and a dataframe called `df_b`.
How can I iterate over each row in `df_a` and (perhaps if a certain condition is met) append it as a row to the bottom of `df_b`?

I'm looking for something like this (which doesn't work):

```
for index, row in df_a.iterrows():
    if row["some_col_val"] == 1:
        df_b.append(row)
```

Comment: It'll be better if you provide some example.

Comment: `pd.concat([df_b,df_a])` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Here's a sample example of what you are solving:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [4,5,6]})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10,20,30], 'col2': [40,50,60]})

for index, row in df_a.iterrows():

    ## write condition

    ## append in df_b
    df_b = df_b.append(row)

print(df_a)

   col1  col2
0    10    40
1    20    50
2    30    60
0     1     4
1     2     5
2     3     6
```